# Is creating a context-free-grammar parser easy?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

Is creating a context-free-grammar parser easy? Can they be created automatically via generators? Are there any paper about this topic?

Comment: No. It is not easy.

Comment: No, it's not easy; yes, there are parser generators; yes, there are papers (and texbooks) about this topic.

Comment: It's easy if you use a parser generator :-) It helps if you know something about context-free grammars.

Comment: Yes, but only if CFG is in some restriction form! You should refer to compiler books for LR parser etc. We have parsing techniques for an arbitrary form of CFG but that would be very slow in `n^2` where `n` is the number of symbols in the language.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done using Earley, GLR or GLL parsing engines.  You can find research papers that sketch how these should be implemented; the basic ideas are pretty simple (check Scholar.google.com and search for these names as index terms).

But production data structures and algorithm details get pretty messy.  The people that build real parser engines like this typically have worked on many such engines before they get to this stage, at least that what is was like for me.  (I've built LALR and GLR parsing engines, as well a recursive descent parser that were autogenerated from grammars).

I suggest you are better off  getting an existing parser generator that uses one of these approaches, rather than trying to build it yourself.   After you've used one for awhile and understand the issues, *then* you might consider looking at the implementation.   Typically not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Is it possible to create a parser for any CFG via a generator?

Comment: Yes, that's the technical claim made by these technologies.   There's a performance cost; these can be pretty expensive to run on CFGs that require effectively unbounded input or are highly ambiguous.   (My company uses GLR parsers to handle some 40 programming languages including the "unparseable with generators" (folk theorem :) C++.  The parsing overhead in practice seems pretty reasonable in most cases.  We've found a few that require additional help to get reasonable parsetimes but we didn't have to change the underlying parser engine.